# line breaking for group actions in latex

Tags: article-writing

When the group $G$ acts on a manifold $M$, we typically use expressions as

> $M$ is a $G$-manifold,

or

> $G$-action on $M$.

If we write those sentences in latex, is it recommended to put $G$ and the latter word together? For instance, if a line ends with "$G$-" and the lext line starts with "manifold", it doesn't look good to me. On the other hand, if I see a line ending with "$G$-mani-", it also bothers me.

Is there any instruction on this?

Comment: This question is not about mathematics and is much better suited to the [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: @Mike Pierce, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110234/can-i-use-both-of-setbuilder-notations-in-one-article

Comment: They think this type of question should be asked here.

Comment: Yeah, it is kind of a weird question. It's not clearly on topic here or on TeX.SE or on the English Language Usage SE. I read your question as *How do you keep something like "$G$-action" from line-wrapping?*, which would be a TeX.SE question like [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67571/no-hyphen-for-a-word). Were you asking how to keep it from hyphenating, or were you asking for guidance on proper mathematical writing style?

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you that it does look odd if the word gets hyphenated for a line-break. So long as it doesn't make the spacing within the line noticeable, I would say yes, definitely keep hyphenated words like that from breaking over multiple lines.